Are there options to change the tick marks length on a metafor forest plot?
How to make tick marks shorter (or longer) in metafor forest plots ?
Tick marks on metafor forest plots should be adapted but I do not found the graphical option to do that.
I have not found any doc on this on the webpage of metafor nor on the web.

The metafor package uses 'base R graphics' and therefore such settings are controlled via par() -- see help(par) for further details. In this case, you can adjust the tcl or tck graphical parameter. Here is an example:
library(metafor)

dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat, slab=paste(author, year, sep=", "))

par(tcl=-0.2, mgp=c(2,0.5,0))

forest(res, addpred=TRUE, xlim=c(-16,7), at=seq(-3,2,by=1), shade="zebra",
       ilab=cbind(tpos, tneg, cpos, cneg), ilab.xpos=c(-9.5,-8,-6,-4.5),
       cex=0.9, header="Author(s) and Year")
text(c(-9.5,-8,-6,-4.5), res$k+2, c("TB+", "TB-", "TB+", "TB-"), cex=0.9, font=2)
text(c(-8.75,-5.25),     res$k+3, c("Vaccinated", "Control"),    cex=0.9, font=2)

I also adjusted the distance of the axis title and axis labels a bit, since this is another setting you may want to adjust if you adjust the length of the tick marks.

Oh yes, thanks a lot for the very quick answer !

If this answers your question, please accept the answer. That way, I get my precious internet points and others know that this question has been answered.
